# Use Ideone api in silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Unable to use the web service provided by [ideone](http://ideone.com/api) in silverlight 3.

When added as a service reference it gives the following warnings as result of which it is unable to generate the required code:

Warning 1:Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType

Warning 2:Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding

Warning 3:Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port

Warning 4:Custom tool warning: No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 3 were found. The generated client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is provided via the constructor.